# Ember.js each loop with external/outbound link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. I am using ember.js to make a basic site. I have an each loop, inside of which I want it to display a variable while linking to an external site (eg. google.com which I have stored as a different variable).

For some reason, when I am doing the  inside the each loop, I am getting the error, "This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid." I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to go to an external site when clicked on. Here is my each loop and the example json.

```
{{#each}}
      {{#link-to 'theme' theme tagName="tr"}}
          <td class="noWrap">{{#link-to 'theme' title}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td>{{#link-to 'theme' this}}<img {{bind-attr src="image"}} \>{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter"><a {{bind-attr href="link"}}>{{price}}</a></td>
          <td>{{description}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter">{{columns}}</td>
      {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}

{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Title',
  price: '$10',
  description: 'random description',
  columns: 1,
  link:'https://google.com',
  image: 'images/image.jpg'
}
```

and this is my theme route

```
App.ThemeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.THEMES.findBy('title', params.title); 
  }
});
```

Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks again!

David B

Comment: What is `theme` in the first link-to? Should that be this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `{{#link-to 'theme' theme tagName="tr"}}` is replaced with `<tr>` , the table row will be rendered without it being a link (unless this is not acceptable, unfortunately the `link-to` helper's purpose at that point is not clear to me).

So the result would be something like,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuvazica/1#/theme/1

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuvazica/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="theme">
  <table>
    {{#each}}
      <tr>
          <td class="noWrap">{{#link-to 'theme' title}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td>{{#link-to 'theme' this}}<img {{bind-attr src="image"}} \>{{/link-to}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter"><a {{bind-attr href="link"}}>{{price}}</a></td>
          <td>{{description}}</td>
          <td class="tdCenter">{{columns}}</td>
       </tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
  </script>
```

By the way, the error that is shown it is due to the parameter `theme` in `{{#link-to 'theme' theme tagName="tr"}}`, if it is removed the error will go away but the rendered html  will not function properly (at least what i noticed in the quick example i provided), because of the `{{#link-to}}` helper at that point.

Comment: Thanks!! I was thinking i needed that #link-to so it would know what to loop through, but obviously I dont. Thanks for the help!!